# how to change the label value after i selected dropdown

Tags: jquery, python, django

i m creating the python project i created the dropdown field in models.py ,then i have to display in html template . I have write the jquery code also.but dint work.

**models.py**

```
addtype = models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=STATE_CHOICES,default='seller')
```

**forms.py**

```
 addtype = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=type.objects.all())
```

**views.py**

```
addtype = product_form.cleaned_data['addtype']
```

**ad.html**

```
<head>

    <script  src="../static/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("111");
        $('#adtype').on('change', function() {

            alert("aa");
                var lb = $('#adtype').val();
                if(lb = "seller")
                {
                    aler("1");
                    $('#seller').hide();
                    $('#buyer').show();

                }
                else
                {

                    $('#buyer').hide();
                    $('#seller').show();
                 }       
        });        
    </script>
 </head>

<p>
     {{ product_form.addtype.errors }}
     <label>Type of Ad:</label>
     <select name="ad"id="adtype">
    <option value="seller">Seller</option>
    <option value="buyer">Buyer</option>
   </select>
</p>

  <label id="seller"> Seller Information</label>
  <label id="buyer" style="display: none;"> Buyer Information</label>
```

The above label want to change. if i click the seller, i want to change labale as seller infomration and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment will always be evaluated as true:

```
if(lb = "seller")
```

Try

```
if(lb == "seller")
```